# Postgres insert two rows into a table containing returned value of previous insert

Tags: postgresql

I've been bumping my head for the last few hours trying to figure out how I can insert an `id` from a previous insert statement and use the returning value to insert into another table and return that into a final table. So in a way I can achieve something like this:

```
with first_insert as (
  insert into table_1 (user_1, user_2)
  values (${user_1}, ${user_2})
  returning id
),
second_insert as (
  insert into table_2 (some_id, 'other columns')
  values 
    ((select id from first_insert), 'stuff'),
    ((select id from first_insert), 'stuff')
  returning id
)
insert into table_3 (some_id, 'other columns')
values ((select id from first_insert), stuff)
```

Now I'm aware that with `CTE's` that it can only return a single select statement. So the SQL isn't valid and will throw an error. I have also tried creating a separate nested cte for the second insert and selecting the second tables value from the third insert to no avail. something like this:

```
with first_insert as (
  insert into table_1 (user_1, user_2)
  values (${user_1}, ${user_2})
  returning id
),
second_insert as (
  insert into table_2 (some_id, 'other columns')
  values 
    ((select id from first_insert), 'stuff')
  returning id
),
third_insert as (
  insert into table_2 (some_id, 'other columns')
  values 
    ((select id from second_insert), 'stuff')
  returning id
)
insert into table_3 (some_id, 'other columns')
values ((select id from third_insert), stuff)
```

This also doesn't work... I'm guessing it's because I already created a cte with that table and can't recognize the `third_insert`. Please let me know if that's why. I'm interested to learn something new and finding the best way to do something similar in a single query. Thank you :)

Comment: "*with CTE's it can only return a single statement*" - not sure what you mean. Your have only a single final statement, why do you think this is invalid? What exactly is the error that is thrown? Your first code should work just fine.

Comment: You can't use a `select` from a cte more than once. After a select it disappears. sorry if my wording is confusing. i edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: You seem to be mistaken about that. As I said, [the code just works](https://dbfiddle.uk/IrbUrb5N). The thing about selecting from the CTE just once is that the query cannot be inlined but will have its result materialised if you use it multiple times. But there's nothing disallowing that.

Comment: Awesome thanks for taking the time to check it i didn't expect it to work... must be something i'm missing in my code base. i upvoted your comment!

Comment: If the actual code from your code base doesn't work, please post it

Comment: @Bergie Thank you for your help! i solved the issue must have been a typo i got a new thrown error.. I also had a unique constraint on that column preventing im from inserting with same value. Im happy people like you are in this community! :)